# How to extract string and write in as multiple lines in text file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, ip-address

New to Python here.

I am trying to get the most active ip address from a log.txt file and print it in another text file. My first step is to get all the ip addresses. Second to sort the most occurring ip address. But I am stuck in the first step which is:

```
with open('./log_input/log.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # loops the lines in teh text file
    for line in f:
        # split line at whitespace
        cols = line.split()

        # get last column
        byte_size = cols[-1]

        # get the first column [0]
        ip_addresses = cols[0]

        # remove brackets
        byte_size = byte_size.strip('[]')

        # write the byte size in the resource file
        resource_file = open('./log_output/resources.txt', 'a')
        resource_file.write(byte_size + '\n')
        resource_file.truncate()
        # write the ip addresses in the host file
        host_file = open('./log_output/hosts.txt', 'a')
        host_file.seek(0)
        host_file.write(ip_addresses + '\n')
        host_file.truncate()

    resource_file.close()
    host_file.close()
```

The problem is in the new host.txt file, it reprints the ip addresses instead of overwriting. I tried this too:

```
    resource_file = open('./log_output/resources.txt', 'w')
    host_file = open('./log_output/hosts.txt', 'w')
```

and `'w+'` and so on.. but `w` or `w+` gives only one ip address in the host file.

Can someone guide me through this?

*Sample Input File*

```
www-c2.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-1.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1659
isdn6-34.dnai.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /images/kscmap-tiny.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2537
isdn6-34.dnai.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 3635 
ix-ftw-tx1-24.ix.netcom.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/count.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 40310
```

Comment: I'd first suggest opening your resource file only once: resource_file = open('./log_output/resources.txt', 'a') should go before you start the for loop. 
Same for the host_file.

Comment: Can you post a few example lines of the input file so we can test?

Comment: _it reprints the ip addresses instead of overwriting_ ... I have no idea what that means. What do you want to be in that file? All addresses with duplicates, all addresses without duplicates?

Comment: One problem is that you write and truncate but don't close the file. So the next `host_file = open('./log_output/hosts.txt', 'a')` opens an outdated version of the file and then as it reassigns `host_file`, the prior loop's data is flushed to the file. Close the thing after you use it or put it in a `with` clause.

Comment: www-c2.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-1.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1659
isdn6-34.dnai.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /images/kscmap-tiny.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2537
isdn6-34.dnai.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 3635
ix-ftw-tx1-24.ix.netcom.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:03:52 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/count.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 40310

Comment: Thanks! Move it to a code block in the question so we can see the line breaks. Do you need the host.txt file or was that just an intermediate step? And what is resources.txt? Do you want to keep that?

Comment: Thank you as well. I dont think I can edit my Questions yet. I need to output the most used ip address in host.txt file. Print() is easy but writing in a new file is a little tricky for me. Resources.txt file is a file where I am trying to solve another issues, where I print the most bandwidth  used by the resources. The issue I am facing is the same in both cases. Either the ip-address is appended or only last one is written in host.txt( or resource.txt)

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` is a handy tool for counting things. Feed it a bunch of text strings and it will create a `dict` mapping the text to the number of times that text is seen. Now counting IP addresses is easy

```
>>> import collections
>>> with open('log.txt') as fp:
...     counter = collections.Counter(line.split(' ', 1)[0].lower() for line in fp)
... 
>>> counter
Counter({'isdn6-34.dnai.com': 2, 'ix-ftw-tx1-24.ix.netcom.com': 1, 'www-c2.proxy.aol.com': 1})
>>> counter.most_common(1)
[('isdn6-34.dnai.com', 2)]
>>>
>>>
>>> with open('most_common.txt', 'w') as fp:
...     fp.write(counter.most_common(1)[0][0])
... 
17
>>> open('most_common.txt').read()
'isdn6-34.dnai.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help and suggestion.. this fixed my problem.

```
with open('./log_input/log.txt', 'r+') as f:

# loops the lines in teh text file
new_ip_addresses = ""
new_byte_sizes = ""
new_time_stamp = ""
resource_file = open('./log_output/resources.txt', 'w')
host_file = open('./log_output/hosts.txt', 'w')
hours_file = open('./log_output/hours.txt', 'w')

for line in f:
    # print re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", line)  # ['Hi all', 'this is', 'an example']

    # split line at whitespace
    cols = line.split(' ')

    #get the time stamp times


    # print(cols[4])

    # get byte sizes from the
    byte_size = cols[-1]
    new_byte_sizes += byte_size

    # get  ip/host
    ip_addresses = cols[0]
    new_ip_addresses += ip_addresses + '\n'

    # remove brackets
    byte_size = byte_size.strip('[]')

# write the byte size in the resource file
print(new_byte_sizes)
resource_file.write(new_byte_sizes)
resource_file.close()

# write the ip addresses in the host file
print(new_ip_addresses)
host_file.write(new_ip_addresses)
host_file.close()

# write the ip addresses in the host file
print(new_ip_addresses)
host_file.write(new_ip_addresses)
host_file.close()
```

Basically assigning the value to the variable inside the for loop and adding new line solved it for me.

`new_ip_addresses += ip_addresses + '\n'`